# How to reformat the following JSON a specific value?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have the following JSON file:

```
   a_lis= [
      {
        "id": "0394820934",
        "obj": [
          {
            "fruit": "mint",
            "origin": "brazil",
            "seller": "unknown",
            "record": false
          }
        ],
        "available": false,
        "count": 0
      },
      {
        "id": "0239840394",
        "obj": [
          {
            "fruit": "grapes",
            "origin": "origin",
            "seller": "unknown",
            "record": false
          },
          {
            "fruit": " ",
            "record": false
          },
          {
            "fruit": "ARN",
            "origin": "destination",
            "seller": "unknown",
            "record": true
          },
          {
            "fruit": " no ",
            "record": false
          },
          {
            "fruit": "apple",
            "origin": "unknown",
            "seller": "walmart",
            "record": false
          }
        ],
        "available": false,
        "count": 0
      },
      {
        "id": "0928293820982309",
        "obj": [
          {
            "fruit": "tomato",
            "origin": "COL",
            "seller": "unknown",
            "record": false
          },
          {
            "fruit": "Watermelon",
            "origin": "destination",
            "seller": "unknown",
            "record": false
          },
          {
            "fruit": " ",
            "record": false
          },
          {
            "fruit": "pear",
            "origin": "return_date",
            "seller": "walmart",
            "record": true
          }
        ],
        "available": false,
        "count": 0,
        "updated": 0
      },
      {
        "id": "23423423",
        "obj": [
          {
            "fruit": "10",
            "origin": "usa",
            "seller": "cotsco",
            "record": false
          }
        ],
        "available": false,
        "count": 0
      },
      {
        "id": "230948",
        "obj": [
          {
            "fruit": " ",
            "record": false
          },
          {
            "fruit": "pear",
            "origin": "adult_companion",
            "seller": "sears",
            "record": true
          },
          {
            "fruit": "apple",
            "record": false
          },
          {
            "fruit": "Watermelon",
            "origin": "Japan",
            "seller": "unknown",
            "record": true
          },
          {
            "fruit": " apple ",
            "record": false
          },
          {
            "fruit": " lemon ",
            "origin": "Canada",
            "seller": "unknown",
            "record": true
          },
          {
            "fruit": " the apple is good ",
            "record": false
          },
          {
            "fruit": " apple ",
            "origin": "COL",
            "seller": "sears",
            "record": true
          }
        ],
        "available": false,
        "count": 0
      }
    ]
```

The above file is a list of dicts. How can I duplicate and append to `a_list` all the sub dictionaries that contain the word 'apple' replacing that word for the word lemon?. For example:

```
a_lis = [
  {
    "id": "0394820934",
    "obj": [
      {
        "fruit": "mint",
        "origin": "brazil",
        "seller": "unknown",
        "record": false
      }
    ],
    "available": false,
    "count": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "0239840394",
    "obj": [
      {
        "fruit": "grapes",
        "origin": "origin",
        "seller": "unknown",
        "record": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": " ",
        "record": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": "ARN",
        "origin": "destination",
        "seller": "unknown",
        "record": true
      },
      {
        "fruit": " no ",
        "record": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": "apple",
        "origin": "unknown",
        "seller": "walmart",
        "record": false
      }
    ],
    "available": false,
    "count": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "0928293820982309",
    "obj": [
      {
        "fruit": "tomato",
        "origin": "COL",
        "seller": "unknown",
        "record": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": "Watermelon",
        "origin": "destination",
        "seller": "unknown",
        "record": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": " ",
        "record": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": "pear",
        "origin": "return_date",
        "seller": "walmart",
        "record": true
      }
    ],
    "available": false,
    "count": 0,
    "updated": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "23423423",
    "obj": [
      {
        "fruit": "10",
        "origin": "usa",
        "seller": "cotsco",
        "record": false
      }
    ],
    "available": false,
    "count": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "230948",
    "obj": [
      {
        "fruit": " ",
        "record": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": "pear",
        "origin": "adult_companion",
        "seller": "sears",
        "record": true
      },
      {
        "fruit": "apple",
        "record": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": "Watermelon",
        "origin": "Japan",
        "seller": "unknown",
        "record": true
      },
      {
        "fruit": " apple ",
        "record": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": " lemon ",
        "origin": "Canada",
        "seller": "unknown",
        "record": true
      },
      {
        "fruit": " the apple is good ",
        "record": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": " apple ",
        "origin": "COL",
        "seller": "sears",
        "record": true
      }
    ],
    "available": false,
    "count": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "0239840394",
    "obj": [
      {
        "fruit": "grapes",
        "origin": "origin",
        "seller": "unknown",
        "record": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": " ",
        "record": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": "ARN",
        "origin": "destination",
        "seller": "unknown",
        "record": true
      },
      {
        "fruit": " no ",
        "record": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": "lemon",
        "origin": "unknown",
        "seller": "walmart",
        "record": false
      }
    ],
    "available": false,
    "count": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "230948",
    "obj": [
      {
        "fruit": " ",
        "record": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": "pear",
        "origin": "adult_companion",
        "seller": "sears",
        "record": true
      },
      {
        "fruit": "lemon",
        "record": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": "Watermelon",
        "origin": "Japan",
        "seller": "unknown",
        "record": true
      },
      {
        "fruit": " lemon ",
        "record": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": " lemon ",
        "origin": "Canada",
        "seller": "unknown",
        "record": true
      },
      {
        "fruit": " the lemon is good ",
        "record": false
      },
      {
        "fruit": " lemon ",
        "origin": "COL",
        "seller": "sears",
        "record": true
      }
    ],
    "available": false,
    "count": 0
  }
]
```

In other words the original dictionaries with the word 'apple' are kept in the list, while a copied version is appended at the original list but with the word lemon? I tried to parse the json file as follows:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
json_output = open('file.json','r')
json_output = json.loads(json_output.read())
```

However, I dont know how to copy the dictionary and look along the nested structure of the dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

Given the many webs of lists and dictionaries here, iterating through them seems extremely laborious.

A simpler way to tackle the problem is just to convert it to a string, replace "apple" with "lemon", then convert it to a new JSON file, and combine your two JSON files into a third, that merges both.

This code works with a slightly-altered JSON file:

```
import json

with open('a_lis-wquotes.json') as fa:
    a = json.load(fa)
    stra = (str(a))
    strb = stra.replace("apple", "lemon")
    strb = strb.replace("'", '"')
    with open('b_lis.json', 'w') as fb:
        fb.write(strb)

with open('a_lis-wquotes.json') as fa:
    a = json.load(fa)
    with open('b_lis.json') as fb:
        b = json.load(fb)
    c = a + b
    strc = str(c)
    strc = strc.replace("'", '"')
    with open('c_lis.json', 'w') as fc:
        fc.write(strc)
```

You'll notice there's a lot of playing around with the quotation marks here.

That's for a few reasons:
- Python's jsondecoder didn't want to import your original JSON, as it lacked double quotes around records marked "true" and "false." I added those quotes to the JSON file before starting (hence the filename "a_lis-wquotes.json"). I did this with find/replace in a text editor. If you can't do this in a text editor because the file is too large, or you have too many files to do this by hand, you can do the same thing in Python by loading the file as a text file, and doing the text replacement there.

- When loading JSON into python and manipulating it in strings, the JSON double-quotes got replaced with single-quotes. That's why I had to write strb to a file before manipulating it as JSON.
- The single/double quotes problem arose again when merging the file a & file b, and writing JSON to a file.

Overall, the output, I believe, matches your desired output (though, again, ignore single/double quote differences):

```
[   {   'available': 'false',
        'count': 0,
        'id': '0394820934',
        'obj': [   {   'fruit': 'mint',
                       'origin': 'brazil',
                       'record': 'false',
                       'seller': 'unknown'}]},
    {   'available': 'false',
        'count': 0,
        'id': '0239840394',
        'obj': [   {   'fruit': 'grapes',
                       'origin': 'origin',
                       'record': 'false',
                       'seller': 'unknown'},
                   {'fruit': ' ', 'record': 'false'},
                   {   'fruit': 'ARN',
                       'origin': 'destination',
                       'record': 'true',
                       'seller': 'unknown'},
                   {'fruit': ' no ', 'record': 'false'},
                   {   'fruit': 'apple',
                       'origin': 'unknown',
                       'record': 'false',
                       'seller': 'walmart'}]},
    {   'available': 'false',
        'count': 0,
        'id': '0928293820982309',
        'obj': [   {   'fruit': 'tomato',
                       'origin': 'COL',
                       'record': 'false',
                       'seller': 'unknown'},
                   {   'fruit': 'Watermelon',
                       'origin': 'destination',
                       'record': 'false',
                       'seller': 'unknown'},
                   {'fruit': ' ', 'record': 'false'},
                   {   'fruit': 'pear',
                       'origin': 'return_date',
                       'record': 'true',
                       'seller': 'walmart'}],
        'updated': 0},
    {   'available': 'false',
        'count': 0,
        'id': '23423423',
        'obj': [   {   'fruit': '10',
                       'origin': 'usa',
                       'record': 'false',
                       'seller': 'cotsco'}]},
    {   'available': 'false',
        'count': 0,
        'id': '230948',
        'obj': [   {'fruit': ' ', 'record': 'false'},
                   {   'fruit': 'pear',
                       'origin': 'adult_companion',
                       'record': 'true',
                       'seller': 'sears'},
                   {'fruit': 'apple', 'record': 'false'},
                   {   'fruit': 'Watermelon',
                       'origin': 'Japan',
                       'record': 'true',
                       'seller': 'unknown'},
                   {'fruit': ' apple ', 'record': 'false'},
                   {   'fruit': ' lemon ',
                       'origin': 'Canada',
                       'record': 'true',
                       'seller': 'unknown'},
                   {'fruit': ' the apple is good ', 'record': 'false'},
                   {   'fruit': ' apple ',
                       'origin': 'COL',
                       'record': 'true',
                       'seller': 'sears'}]},
    {   'available': 'false',
        'count': 0,
        'id': '0394820934',
        'obj': [   {   'fruit': 'mint',
                       'origin': 'brazil',
                       'record': 'false',
                       'seller': 'unknown'}]},
    {   'available': 'false',
        'count': 0,
        'id': '0239840394',
        'obj': [   {   'fruit': 'grapes',
                       'origin': 'origin',
                       'record': 'false',
                       'seller': 'unknown'},
                   {'fruit': ' ', 'record': 'false'},
                   {   'fruit': 'ARN',
                       'origin': 'destination',
                       'record': 'true',
                       'seller': 'unknown'},
                   {'fruit': ' no ', 'record': 'false'},
                   {   'fruit': 'lemon',
                       'origin': 'unknown',
                       'record': 'false',
                       'seller': 'walmart'}]},
    {   'available': 'false',
        'count': 0,
        'id': '0928293820982309',
        'obj': [   {   'fruit': 'tomato',
                       'origin': 'COL',
                       'record': 'false',
                       'seller': 'unknown'},
                   {   'fruit': 'Watermelon',
                       'origin': 'destination',
                       'record': 'false',
                       'seller': 'unknown'},
                   {'fruit': ' ', 'record': 'false'},
                   {   'fruit': 'pear',
                       'origin': 'return_date',
                       'record': 'true',
                       'seller': 'walmart'}],
        'updated': 0},
    {   'available': 'false',
        'count': 0,
        'id': '23423423',
        'obj': [   {   'fruit': '10',
                       'origin': 'usa',
                       'record': 'false',
                       'seller': 'cotsco'}]},
    {   'available': 'false',
        'count': 0,
        'id': '230948',
        'obj': [   {'fruit': ' ', 'record': 'false'},
                   {   'fruit': 'pear',
                       'origin': 'adult_companion',
                       'record': 'true',
                       'seller': 'sears'},
                   {'fruit': 'lemon', 'record': 'false'},
                   {   'fruit': 'Watermelon',
                       'origin': 'Japan',
                       'record': 'true',
                       'seller': 'unknown'},
                   {'fruit': ' lemon ', 'record': 'false'},
                   {   'fruit': ' lemon ',
                       'origin': 'Canada',
                       'record': 'true',
                       'seller': 'unknown'},
                   {'fruit': ' the lemon is good ', 'record': 'false'},
                   {   'fruit': ' lemon ',
                       'origin': 'COL',
                       'record': 'true',
                       'seller': 'sears'}]}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however I got a `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 146 (char 145)` in `     14     with open('../Downloads/b_lis.json') as fb:
---> 15         b = json.load(fb)` maybe its not finding the words?

Comment: Is the JSON exactly what you have above?

Comment: yes, the first part is working well, however the second part of the code is not working... any idea of what to do?

Comment: The error suggests that the file being written (b_lis.json) isn't being written correctly as JSON, and then the JSON decoder is having problems opening it. The code works on my end. Is there anything even a little bit different between the JSON you're starting with and the one above, or the code you're using and the code above?

Comment: Note that I altered your JSON by adding double quotes to values marked true and false throughout the file.